# Runtime conversion of an icon to an ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written an application which gets file icons from the OS and binds to them, but since [System.Drawing.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.aspx) objects can't be used as [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx)'s in the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control, I had to write a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

After searching a bit I arrived at the following code, which I am using at the moment:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    Icon ico = (value as Icon);
    Bitmap bits = ico.ToBitmap();
    MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();

    // add the stream to the image streams collection so we can get rid of it later
    _imageStreams.Add(strm);
    bits.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = strm;
    bitmap.EndInit();

    // freeze it here for performance
    bitmap.Freeze();
    return bitmap;
}
```

and I have three questions:

1. Is there a better solution you could suggest?
2. What's the best way to ultimately close the `MemoryStream`s used, as the code here is called automatically by the binding system? (They are never manually instantiated, as you might notice I am adding the streams to a collection where I call `Close()` on them in the destructor but I don't think it is a nice solution).
3. Related to the previous question, when I try to close the stream before the end of the function, the image appears empty even if I call [Stream.Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush.aspx) before that. Why is this?

Comment: I try not to use the image files, you could add the images inside a resource dictionary and then would use a DataTrigger for setting the image resource you need. If you think you can serve, put some of your XAML code and we can apply

Comment: Thanks @Mate, i am actually getting the icons through a call to Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path); so i can't declare them ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had success with the following when trying to assign an icon in my project resources (WindowIcon) to the Window.Icon ImageSource:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;

...

Icon someIcon = Properties.Resources.WindowIcon;
Bitmap someBitmap = someIcon.ToBitmap();
this.Icon = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(someBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks @Heliac, i am actually getting the icons through a call to Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path); so i can't declare them ahead.